# AutoML Vertex AI - How to set continuous value for labels and default values?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, computer-vision, google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I have an image dataset where it needs multi-labeling support. Additionally, there is a task that needs a count of how many of a specific item there is in each photo. Therefore, I need an input where the user can specify the number (from 0-100 for example).

Is there anyway to do this? Additionally, is there a way to set default values to the labels?

Answer (score 0):

To specify the number of labels, you can use a YAML schema file and use some input files as it is shown in the following documentation[1].

There is a way to specify default values to labels using the default split[2]. This split automatically performs a data split for you, using the `ml_use`, where you only have to set up a value.

[1]https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-image#multi-label-classification

[2]https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/general/ml-use#default